# shinyjs::enable UI widget on shiny app launch

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm using `shinyjs` to enable and disable a UI widget (`inputId="check_buttons"`). Currently the widget is only enabled after the user clicks to go button (`input$go`). Is it possible to have the UI widget `check_buttons` enabled be default when the app is launched?

```
observeEvent(input$go, 
  {
  shinyjs::enable("check_buttons")
})

observeEvent({input$select_box_input
              input$radio_button_input
              },
  {
  shinyjs::disable("check_buttons")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `observeEvent` to disable the `check_buttons` widget is being triggered when the `input$select_box_input`/`input$radio_button_input` widgets are initialized.  You can use the `ignoreInit` argument of `observeEvent` to bypass this behavior:

> ignoreInit
>
> If TRUE, then, when this observeEvent is first created/initialized, ignore the handlerExpr (the second argument), whether it is otherwise supposed to run or not. The default is FALSE. See Details.

Minimal example with the behavior implemented:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
      actionButton('go', 'go'),
      radioButtons('radio_button_input', 'radio', choices = c('a','b')),
      checkboxInput('select_box_input', 'check', value=TRUE),
      checkboxGroupInput('check_buttons', 'boxes', choices = c('1','2'))
    )
  ),
  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$go, {
                 shinyjs::enable("check_buttons")
    })
    
    observeEvent({
      input$radio_button_input
      input$select_box_input
      }, {
        shinyjs::disable("check_buttons")
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  })
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does answer the question. Unfortunately my use case does not match my example. I think it is because `radio_button_input` is generated by `renderUI` in my server.R script rather than in the ui script.

Comment: Hard to answer the question you meant to ask without a reproducible example of your use case.  I'd suggest posting a small app (like in my answer) that covers your use case.  Wouldn't want anyone else to spend time answering the question when there might be other hidden requirements.

Comment: Right, I'm going to mark your answer because it does answer this question. Will post another question later. Thanks.